# How to add a dependency (ensure insert order) without a foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

**Note: this is not a real scenario so don't over analyze why people are being emailed from a trigger or -why- we are doing it, I am more interested in the how**

I have the following three tables

```
Classroom
ClassroomTime
ClassroomPerson
```

[image]

We have a trigger on `ClassroomPerson` for when a person is added it automatically emails them the times for the classroom.

When setting up a classroom in EF, it correct creates the classroom first but there is no explict order if ClassroomTime or ClassroomPerson gets created next. It so happens that ClassroomPerson is created first, so the trigger fails because ClassroomTime has no times yet.

Is there a way to enforce that EF creates in this order:

```
1) Classroom
2) ClassroomTime
3) ClassroomPerson
```

when providing all data.

One hack we thought of was to have ClassroomPerson's ClassroomId is a FK to `ClassroomTime` and not `Classroom`.

The more straight forward solution would be to have EF enforce the trigger behavior by executing the behavior itself and not rely on a trigger but  then things outside EF need to have context of this behavior

Comment: Only by enforcing the insert order yourself in multiple `SaveChanges` calls enclosed in a transaction.